# Why do I need to use a type assertion in my declaration which assigns a variable to null?

Tags: typescript

I'm puzzled by why the type for variable `a` below is not `LoadStatus` even though I explicitly put it in the declaration:

```
type LoadStatus = 'succeess'|'failure'|null;

let a: LoadStatus = null;
let b = null as LoadStatus;
a; // type is null
b; // type is LoadStatus
```

I inspected the types using Typescript playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. If that were not the case, miscellaneous type mechanisms would be significantly less useful. For [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=106&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gQwCYGVgOAVwM5QLxQDk2mAxqRNtoVAD5EBmCAlgDaYBOEN9Adpq1YBuAFAjWEYFAQAuWIlTosuAv0GiJUgEb4oa1tNzxkaDDlEIoQqAHobUUJCjNc+sVut2H4aC-kmlHDEvADkBAz9SOF4ANwgOYAgkBzhGFnYuQgAaFOlWAHcEEFwuLA5eaShsQNxqjmZeAHMRR2gAYWi4hONFM2wAHgAVKAgAD0TeJCMFU2UAPl1hsYmpvXCoAH40tk5uKDlB0RafKC4SVmAAQV0O2PjgHtmcfta4Bmk5z3smHa5RVtOlAEwAAQjdOvdHjUXj43lAtJ9bPZiGQKFQeNsMtwcrw4FIuiAoAALCCsMAMARiSwEACsX0qfmqbAMuKkCCozEavAQWgkuTxJI4DiJDUauGARIQFSQlFI9S0SRy2FSjlFVWAzKgYA4eIgpGA4pJUBiCHqPIkQA):

```
type LoadStatus = 'success' | 'failure' | null;

let a: LoadStatus = null;
let b = null as LoadStatus;
a ; // type is null

b; // type is LoadStatus

// null is converted to 'failure', so that always a string is returned
type ConvertLoadStatus<T extends LoadStatus> = T extends null ? 'failure' : T;

type resultA = ConvertLoadStatus<typeof a>; // failure;
type resultB = ConvertLoadStatus<typeof b>; // 'success' | 'failure', not very helpful

a = 5; // a is still not assignable to other things than described, so typing still protects the variable
```

Another example would be `if` statements when checking for [null or undefined](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDYQCrmgXigbwQC4oBnYAJwEsA7AcwBooAjEmgVyWYgoF8oAPlA6pUAbgBQEgGbsaAY2BUA9jSgATZQGVlSCMAAWtOgApisRCnRZIASgISoUKtLNQAhHhGp7%20R06gEKAB6YMDnUgJzcmp6JlZhTm4%20fycEADog0PD5BDUaZQB3FmgEeXkIUlIIdVSQsIAJIqhC5XZUdRboCAA3HhLA5nQoYGVA8srIoJdnYEDUQoQQSPIlmotkNExsAH5-Xn8MrLCAeWYAKwhFCKgwZSqqIZAoAHJvF4kDiSA):

```
type ExampleType = {a: string, b: number} | null;

function doSomething(a: ExampleType) {
  if(a != null) {
    a // a is {a: string, b: number}
    a.a // a can now be accessed
    // How would we ever be able to access a if it always stayed ExampleType?
  }
  a.a // Object is possibly 'null'
}
```

**Edit**: As @Boug pointed out, it's all described under [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html).

Comment: Thanks for the first example. It helps to know that a is still only assignable to valid values of LoadStatus.

Answer (score 1):

This is called narrowing union type.

Check the documentation here and you will understand why it is as it is [Docu](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html)

The following example is very much like yours [narrowing example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments)

Comment: This line helped me understand it: "assignability is always checked against the declared type".  As long as the value assigned is a valid option for the declared type, ts  will consider your variable to be of type <typeof declared value> - whatever that value is in the current scope.  It allows for type safety without being *too* strict.  Check out [this ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gQwCYGVgOAVwM5QLxTbABOAlgHYDmUAPlOZgLYBGExA3AFCcA2EwUBAC5YiVOiy4CAVi58BzfFGmDc8ZGgw4uCdlAD0+qKEhRSuBjx6dmew8fDRzojRJzdOANwTEoACwgrOCUEKAAqKABGAAZuUIIAcnI4SATub18AoJDwqOigA)

Comment: ...you can assign `a` to either a number or string value, and typesript will not complain.  But if you try to use it as a number when its value has be assigned to a string, typescript will recognize this and tell you its a problem.  Pretty nice feature to allow some level of dynamic typing in typescript without losing type safety